# Exception when add data into TableViewer

Tags: java, exception, jface, tableviewer

I have 2 TableViewer controls in a composite (Supposed they are : **viewer1**, **viewer2**). When initialize application, one "**viewer1**" is filled data from server while "**viewer2**" is set null.

```
viewer1.setInput(getData());
viewer2.setInput(null);
```

Now I want to change some object from viewer1 to **viewer2** via a context menu, the first time add is successful, but the next time when I fill object to **viewer2**, I always get this exception:
 **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**

This didn't happen if **viewer2** contain some objects in advance, it only happens when **viewer2** is empty.
This is the way I add move some data from **viewer1** to **viewer2** :

```
//get selected objects in Viewer1
IStructuredSelection selection= (IStructuredSelection) viewer1.getSelection();
if(selection!=null){
            selectedList=(List<MyObject>)selection.toList();
            for(MyObject obj: selectedList){
                //do something here
            }
            //remove all
            ((List<MyObject>)viewer1().getInput()).removeAll(selectedList);
            viewer1.refresh();
        }
//viewer1 get above List
if((List<MyObject>)viewer2.getInput()==null)
 viewer2.setInput(selectedList);
else {
 ((List<MyObject>)viewer2.getInput()).addAll(selectedList);  //(Line Error)
}
viewer2.refresh;
```

It works well at the first time in the IF condition, but the next time when **viewer2** contained some data, I always get exception at above error line.
@Krumelur , I added stacktrace that I got:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2011-12-27 16:26:50.660
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.saltlux.om.client.customwidgets.NeutralSetWidget.getReviewFromOtherWidget(NeutralSetWidget.java:39)
    at com.saltlux.om.client.customwidgets.NeutralSetWidget$1.handleEvent(NeutralSetWidget.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at com.saltlux.om.client.customwidgets.PositiveSetWidget.add2TrainingSet(PositiveSetWidget.java:107)
    at com.saltlux.om.client.customwidgets.TrainingReviewWidget$10.run(TrainingReviewWidget.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.saltlux.om.client.Application.start(Application.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Please help me out. Thanks so much for any answer!

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all implementations of `java.util.List` interface support `addAll()` method. For example, the one that is returned by [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) does not and this is the method used by [`StructuredSelection.toList()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse/jface/3.7.0/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/StructuredSelection.java#192).

Comment: Hi martti, it happens only when viewer was set NULL in advance. If it contained some data, addAll() method work well all the time. I guess it's not problem here

Comment: Thanks Martti, it's more clear for now. When I check this
viewer2.getInput().getClass() --> It's "java.util.Arrays$ArrayList"
So I couldn't use addAll() method with this class type.
I changed the way to setInput for viewer2 as follow and it works fine:
`viewer2.setInput(new MyObject()); //rather than setInput(null)`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the exception is thrown from your content provider. Have you checked that your content provider actually accepts the List? What content provider do you use?

Comment: Hi Krumelur!
`viewer1.setContentProvider(new ContentProvider<MyObject>());`
It of course accept ContentProvider,because I could setInput normally in the first time.

`public class ContentProvider<M> implements IStructuredContentProvider {

 @Override
 public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
  if(inputElement != null) {
   List<M> models = (List<M>) inputElement;
   return models.toArray();
  }
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void dispose() {
 }

 @Override
 public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
 }

}`

Answer (score 0):

I found out a workaround, change the way to initialize input for **viewer2** as follow:

```
viewer2.setInput(new ArrayList<MyObject>())
```

Before I set NUll for input, and couldn't use method addAll() to add more objectes to tableviewer.
Thanks all for your help.
Best regards!